# PHP Dynamic Pagetitle with pageloading script

Tags: php, dynamic, title

Good Evening!

I ran into a little problem with my current website project.
So i wanted to have dynamic page titles and maybe descriptions.
I tried doing it with a seperate header file and including it then through PHP.
The Problem is, i'm using a pageload script, so that my content of the homepage for example is stored in: `pages/home.php` and gets then included into the `index.php` of my website.

I could add some php variables to my `home.php` but it won't be included into the header where i already defined the destination of the variable of course.
I assume that loading the `home.php` where the variables are saved in, after the index.php just won't recognize it.
------------------------------------------------------------------

My `index.php` with pageloading script:
https://gist.github.com/loohney/17f1406a7e5662b68448106cc13ce72c

My `home.php`:
https://gist.github.com/loohney/3ee7425b75a2bee5dc2756ed858a9d62
I hope someone can help me out with this.
Maybe there is even a better way to do this.
Every kind of help and tips are much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: If everything in your home.php is stored in variables, why don't you just include it before everything else on `index.php`? That way the `$pageTitle`-variable will be available whenever.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thats not the case. My home.php contains text, divs, and much more content.

Comment: Then you should rethink how you do things. Because it's not possible the way you have it set up right now. Either, you'll have to have double the includes, or you need to rethink how you create the home.php (and other pages). If you create home.php with variables containing the content, you can use those same variables on other pages as well, and just change the include in the index, so that you can load multiple includes with the same code, and avoid any issues with where on the page stuff has to go (since you load it at the beginning).